# PHP работа с процентами

Tags: php

Не могу понять как работают в php проценты.

Например:

php:

```
1%13 = 1
13%13 = 0
```

Калькулятор:

```
1%13 = 0.13
13%13 = 1.69
```

Прошу разъяснить в чём моя проблема недопонимания

Comment: `%` в пхп - это оператор получения остатка от деления. А проблема ваша в том, что вы не хотите открыть мануал по пхп и ознакомиться с ним.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на ruSO! Символ % в PHP не означает процентного отношения чисел. Это [оператор](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php), результат работы которого - остаток деления.

Answer (score 2):

> *как работают в php проценты*

В PHP так же, как и в математике: 1% == 0.01

```
echo 0.01 * 13; // 0.13
echo 0.13 * 13; // 1.69
```

Символ `%` внешне похож на клавишу "Проценты" любого калькулятора, но в PHP это оператор деления по модулю. В результате вы получите целочисленный остаток от деления:

```
echo (2 % 2); // 0
echo (3 % 2); // 1
echo (4 % 2); // 0
```